# Which version of ASP.NET MVC ships with Mono 2.10?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono

I know ASP .NET MVC libraries are now being shipped with [Mono](http://mono-project.com) but I cannot find exact version information.

Which exactly version of ASP.NET MVC is supported in the latest Mono release, [Mono 2.10.1](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be more concise:

Mono 2.10 ships with ASP.NET MVC2 (and also MVC1) out of the box. It is the actual Microsoft code.

ASP.NET MVC 3 should work if you include the assemblies in your project ([See the release notes](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#ASP.NET_MVC3_Support)).

MonoDevelop will allow you to work with all of these but the 'new solution' scaffolding for ASP.NET MVC still builds the skeleton of an ASP.NET MVC1 app.

Comment: @gaearon - To migrate a MD MVC skeleton to MVC2 you can open the two Web.config files (main one and one under 'Views') and search and replace 1.0.0.0 to 2.0.0.0. Similarly, you can select the 4.0 profile and then replace all 3.5.0.0 with 4.0.0.0 to be using MVC2 with ASP.NET 4.0 (you can then use <%: for example). Not elegant but it will get you there. Of course, you can start a solution in Visual Studio and then open it in MD.

Comment: Now that Razor is Open Source [MVC 3 was added to Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/3f4e22a0ce7206b9321991123893a63b2dd398d4). So, MVC 3 (or even possibly 4) will ship with Mono 2.12 and later.

Answer (score 5):

Copying from the release notes:

http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#ASP.NET_MVC3_Support

> See below for notes on Razor and
>   WebPages.
>
> Although ASP.NET MVC3 is open source
>   and licensed under the terms of the
>   MS-PL license, it takes a few
>   dependencies on new libraries that are
>   not open source nor are they part of
>   the Microsoft.NET Framework.
>
> At this point we do not have open
>   source implementations of those
>   libraries, so we can not ship the full
>   ASP.NET MVC3 stack with Mono (We still
>   ship ASP.NET MVC 1 and MVC 2 with Mono
>   for your deployment enjoyment).
>
> This Mono release however has enough
>   bug fixes and patches that you will be
>   able to run ASP.NET MVC3 sites with
>   it.
>
> Since these new dependencies were not
>   part of Microsoft.NET, they typically
>   are referenced in your project and
>   deployed in the bin/ directory of your
>   ASP.NET site. Make sure that you
>   remove the
>   Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll
>   library from your site when deploying
>   to Mono, to allow Mono to use its own
>   implementation that integrates ASP.NET
>   MVC3 with Mono.
>
> To run your web sites, use our 4.0
>   profile programs:
>
> - xsp4 for quick testing
> - mod-mono-server4.exe for Apache
> - hosting fastcgi-mono-server4.exe for FastCGI servers
>
> Razor and WebPages
>
> If you downloaded the Microsoft
>   binaries for ASP.NET MVC3, you will
>   have a few new libraries, the WebPages
>   framework that allows simple web sites
>   to be built and the Razor template
>   engine/
>
> You can use both of those binaries
>   with Mono 2.10.
>
> It is possible to get up and running
>   with Razor and cshtml just by
>   installing this release and running
>   xsp4 on any directory that contains
>   the bin/ assemblies and creating a
>   .cshtml file.